# How to use "temporaryUrl" with custom cname in Laravel::Storage with Amazon S3 -> CloudFront and using a Cname

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, laravel-filesystem

I have a file in S3, that with CloudFront using a cname (with amazon SSL Certificate) while the file is public I can access it without problems using the URL.

Valid examples in public files:

```
https://xxxxxxxxxxxxx.cloudfront.net/media/logos/logo1.png
https://cdn.{mydomain.com}/media/logos/logo1.png
https://s3.amazonaws.com/{mys3bucketname}/media/logos/logo1.png
```

In laravel

```
$disk = Storage::disk('cnames3');
$tempUrl = $disk->temporaryUrl($file, now()->addMinutes(5));
```

The best option I found was:
[Should I use CloudFront together as TemporaryUrl for sensitive files in s3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51586344/should-i-use-cloudfront-together-as-temporaryurl-for-sensitive-files-in-s3)

```
'cnames3' => [
        'driver' => 's3',
        'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
        'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
        'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
        'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
        'url' => env('AWS_URL'),
        'endpoint' => env('AWS_ENDPOINT'),
]

=====
.env
AWS_BUCKET={mys3bucketname}
AWS_ENDPOINT=https://xxxxxxxxxxxxx.cloudfront.net
AWS_URL=https://cdn.{mydomain.com}
```

but the URL that I produced includes the name of the bucket, and so it does not work for me, since it denies me access.

```
https://cdn.{mydomain.com}/{mys3bucketname}/media/logos/logoprivate.png?{params}
```

**how can I get a URL compatible with CNAME, or what can I do so I can use my own domain with signed URLs; I look for this format:**

```
https://cdn.{mydomain.com}/media/logos/logoprivate.png?{params}
```

if I have the private file and use "temporaryUrl" without endpoint
it returns a valid url:

```
 https://s3.amazonaws.com/{mys3bucketname}/media/logos/logoprivate.png?{params}
```

but without my domain, which does not work for me, I have been looking for a solution for hours, I hope you can help this beginner in the subject

Comment: did you try adding `bucket_endpoint => true` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Assuming that CloudFront with CNAME is already working)

> in options of CloudFrontDistributions>{yourCFID} 
>   In Origins tab edit:
>
> Origin Access Identity -> Use an Identity
>
> Restrict Bucket Access: yes (and Yes, Update Bucket Policy)
>
> In Default Cache Behavior Settings:
>
> Restrict Viewer Access
>   (Use Signed URLs or
>   Signed Cookies) = YES
>
> Trusted Signers = SELF

1.- First create Private Key from CloudFront

[Creating CloudFront Key Pairs for Your Trusted Signers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-trusted-signers.html)

2.-

```
composer require league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3
```

OR

```
composer require aws/aws-sdk-php
```

3.- 
Create functions:
[Signing CloudFront URLs for Private Distributions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/v3/developer-guide/service_cloudfront-signed-url.html)

Example:

```
 use Aws\CloudFront\CloudFrontClient;
```

...

```
//$filesystemDisk = "s3"
private function signUrl($filesystemDisk, $resourceKey = null)
{
    $cloudFront = new CloudFrontClient([
        'region'  => config('filesystems.disks.' . $filesystemDisk . '.region'),
        'version' => '2014-11-06',
    ]);
    // Set up parameter values for the resource
    //example
    $resourceKey = 'https://cdn.mydomain.com/media/logos/logoprivate.jpg';
    $expires = time() + 200;

// Create a signed URL for the resource using the canned policy
        $signedUrlCannedPolicy = $cloudFront->getSignedUrl([
            'url'         => $resourceKey,
            'expires'     => $expires,
            'private_key' => '/path/to/keys/amazon/cloudfront/private/pk-APKFYWFAKEFAKEFAKEIQ.pem',
            'key_pair_id' => 'APKFYWFAKEFAKEFAKEIQ',
        ]);

        return $signedUrlCannedPolicy;
    }
```

4.- Done; you get (with your cname):

```
https://cdn.{mydomain.com}/media/logos/logoprivate.jpg?{params}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to set `bucket_endpoint` to `true` in config then it doesn't append `bucket name` in your domain.

```
'cnames3' => [
        'driver' => 's3',
        'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
        'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
        'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
        'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
        'url' => env('AWS_URL'),
        'bucket_endpoint' => true,  //add this 
        'endpoint' => env('AWS_ENDPOINT'),
]
```

You can check here https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php/blob/master/src/S3/S3Client.php

Comment: now if it is the right format! -> but it does not work <-: I was reading a bit more, and I do not know if it is because the signed format is different when using cloudfront:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/v3/developer-guide/service_cloudfront-signed-url.html

Comment: 3 years later, a true savior!